# Duplicating Onepage Block to a Custom Page

Tags: magento-1.9

anyone could give me a tips or any kind of possible solution or good approach in doing this?.

My objective is to make a custom page that has the same onepage block on it
(the step by step procedure until placing final order)(please see the image)
[image: onepage block]

let us say, we have the original checkout/onepage, but i also want a duplicate that goes by checkout/customname that has the same onepage block.

is it possible?

if it is, what is the good approach to do it?

by the way, im fine with doing it using `Action` (checkout/onepage/customname) than of `Controller`(checkout/customname).

ps: if you are going to ask why make two, the answer is,because two different user will be accessing two different checkout page. why? I'm afraid I cant answer that.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In magento you should not edit the core files. So first you have create a [custom module](http://blog.baobaz.com/en/blog/magento-module-create-your-own-controller). With your controller.

Now to get the onepage checkout content in your page. Add below code in your layout file.

```
<yourmodule_yourcontroller_index>
    <update handle="checkout_onepage_index"/>
</yourmodule_yourcontroller_index>
```

Refer this link for [update handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661107/what-does-the-update-element-do-in-magento-layout-xml)

Comment: Yes! it works like charm. <update> tag is what ive been looking for. thank you!